# What exactly does ground mean?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground

I am completely blind, and I'm trying to make a tactile drawing of how electricity flows in a circuit.

A circuit implies that something is circular. So, at 12:00, you'd have one pole, and at 6:00 you'd have another pole. Electricity can flow from one pole to another clockwise or anticlockwise. I know that when current flows in the same direction, is direct. When the flow of electricity changes at a fixed interval, it is called alternating. That's why we have mains hum.

You can attach different things in your circuit, like an  appliance at 3:00, and a radio at 9:00.

If there is an opening in your circuit, electricity cannot flow until the circuit is closed.

So, how exactly does ground work, and are there any analogous concepts that can be used to explain what it means?
This web site has some pretty good analogies to imagine how voltage, current, and resistence works. Unfortunately, does not talk about ground. https://www.howequipmentworks.com/electricity_basics/

Comment: Ground is the reference point so that you can evaluate the voltages at other nodes of the circuit.

Comment: If I understand your confusion correctly, the idea is that all ground symbols in a circuit are connected; the symbol is just so that you don't have a ton of wires all over the place.

Comment: Correction: All the ground symbols of the same type. There might be multiple grounds (earth ground, chassis ground, maybe separate grounds for digital and analog sides of a system, etc) in sufficiently complicated circuits.

Comment: Appliances are usually connected in parallel to each other, not in series. So instead of imagining a circle with appliances at different points, try to imagine multiple circles of different radii, all intersecting the battery. In addition to the battery, which is common, each of these circles have an appliance in series with the battery. Ground is a common point, usually the battery negative, but in principle it can be anywhere as long as it is common. For mains, simply substitute a power station, or your breaker box, for the battery.

Comment: Voltage is always a difference between two points. If you say "point X has 156V" then this doesn't mean anything until you say in reference to what other point. When not mentioned, this point is GND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better analogy is that the circuit is the line at the edge of the clock face.

Break the circuit at 9 o'clock, and connect a battery in series. Break the circuit at 3 o'clock, and connect a lamp in series. Current flows through the circuit.

There is a voltage between 12 and 6 o'clock. That's a differential voltage, the voltage between them. It represents the battery voltage, and the voltage on the bulb.

If we call 6 o'clock 0v, or ground, as we're allowed to pick any arbitrary point on a circuit and call it any voltage we like, then we can refer to our 12 o'clock voltage as a voltage with respect to ground. It's still the same differential voltage, but we've stated what our reference is.

Let's say we have two isolated circuits. The voltage between them is undefined. If we connect a wire between one circuit and the other, no current will flow. If we now pick a point on each circuit, and connect each point to ground, that establishes a common reference, and now a voltage can be defined between points on one and the other circuit. Another wire between the two circuits would allow a current to flow.

Comment: You mentioned series. What's the difference between series and parallels? I noticed that toys, and other items that use cylindrical abatteries have contact springs facing opposite directions.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony series involves physically breaking a wire, hence my specifying 'break the circuit at ...'. The two wire ends created by the break are now connected to the two poles of the battery or lamp. If we took another lamp, and connected two wires, one from each pole, to 12 and to 6 o'clock, that lamp would be in parallel with the lamp at 3. If instead, we broke the circuit at 5 o'clock, and connected those two wire ends to the new lamp, that would be in series with the circuit.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony There is a slight confusion many have with the concept that in the original circuit, both battery and lamp are connected by wires to 12 o'clock and 6 o'clock. Are they in series or parallel? As one is a power source, and the other is a power sink, we usually identify them as being in series, all the current produced by the battery flows through the lamp. If we had two lamps in parallel, then the current from the battery would divide, some flowing through one lamp and some through the other. Two lamps in parallel, with a battery in series.

Answer (score 0):

Ground by definition means a common zero volt reference.

In electronics a power supply can be isolated by a transformer and therefore floating for the DC circuit,  so the 0 V reference can be floating from earth ground, another common reference point. Sometimes there are situations where they are connected such as anti-PC, where earth ground Is bonded to the metal shall see and is also connected to the 0 V DC for noise reduction and shunting away RF that might be radiating like an antenna from the case.